# Fonts in RStudio presentation with reveal.js in utf-8

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, reveal.js

How can I change fonts in a reveal.js powered Rstudio presentation - .rmd header:

```
---
title: "Title with utf-8 signs ą ę ł ó"
output: revealjs::revealjs_presentation
slide_level: 2
---

# R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
```

So that it handles utf-8 letters correctly?
Currently it shows them (I'm saving my .rmd file with utf-8 encoding) but makes them big and ugly after knitting.

[image]

I'm basically trying to compile an introductory R course presentation for my class and looking for the simplest way, that won't use powerpoint.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using RStudio button knit try generating presentation from console

```
library(revealjs)
library(rmarkdown)
rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd', encoding = "UTF-8")
```